# Using Arduino RS232 to a modem (only RS232)

Tags: serial, uart

I am a newbie to the arduino world. And am trying to work out a configuration that does not involve USB.

I wonder if this configuration will work.

Are there any 3g modems that work on Rs232 interface. That should get rid of the USB compatibility that costs 3 times a arduino.

Comment: I'd suggest buying a 3g/gprs shield, or the [adafruit fona](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1946). That way you already have some sample code, and don't have to figure out everything yourself.

Comment: I am ruling out usb completely since a usb compliant host device increases the cost of the solution 3 fold. I need a rs232 interface, speed is not my requirement. I need to send 150 bytes every 60 seconds. Cost is the `only factor` for me at this time.

Comment: Just corrected the subject line.

Comment: There are more TTL/UART 3G modems than RS-232 3G modems.

Comment: In Aus: http://www.maxon.com.au   Arduino doesn't have RS232 however, so like for a TTL/UART interface as Ignacio suggests.

Comment: You might want to consider something with native USB support like a raspberry pi instead of the Arduino.